# Changing 'Emulate 3 Button mouse option' when entering sculpt mode?

Tags: python, add-on, sculpting, customization

I would like to make addon that every time I enter sculpt mode it turns on "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" and when I leave it will turn off.

I am no programmer, I tried to find some parts of code and get it together, I will post it in here. It´s somehow working but for some reason in new projects it´s not working at all, only after reinstalling addon:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Emulate 3 Button Mouse",
    "blender": (2, 91, 2),
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy

handle = object() 

def notify_test(*args):
    print( "Mode:", bpy.context.mode )
    bpy.context.preferences.inputs.use_mouse_emulate_3_button = bpy.context.object.mode == 'SCULPT'

subscribe_to = bpy.types.Object, "mode"

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(1, 2, 3),
    notify=notify_test,
    )

def register():
    bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(1, 2, 3),
    notify=notify_test,
    )

def unregister():
    pass
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Q:** What's wrong and how to fix that bug?

Comment: The following script should work: https://pasteall.org/gGNy/raw Can you test it and report back?

Comment: It´s working until for example I open my project again next day its not working again. Then I need to reinstall addon in order to work again or when I open older project it´s the same problem

Comment: Cool. Yeah, needs to be *enabled* per file using application handlers (on file load)... but it's working as expected? For now you can just copy/paste my code into the text editor and run it per session.

Comment: Oh sry, now I realized that code you posted was in that link. I was kinda confused. Previously I was talking about that my script again.

*And I tried you code and it was working. Previously I did not get what you mean by enabled per file. Now I get it and it seems to work :-D 
I really appreciate your effort to help and also thanks for editing my question :-)